# Posso criar uma lista dentro de um objeto em python?

Tags: python

tenho uma dúvida posso declarar uma lista dentro de um objeto em Python?
Se sim, faria esse objetivo, e como manipularia(adicionar, imprimir..)
alguém tem algum exemplo ou referência onde possa estudar isso?

tipo..

```
class Veiculo(object):

    def __init__(self, id, valor, lista_id_vinculado[]):
        self.id=id
        self.valor=valor
        self.lista_id_vinculado[]=lista_id_vinculado[]
```

Comment: Olá andgualberto, conseguiu testar a minha resposta? Caso tenha dado certo, peço por gentileza que marque como certa. Se precisar de ajuda estou a disposição. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo que segue declarei uma lista `ex_proprietarios` dentro da classe `Veiculo`. 
O método `add_ex_proprietarios` adiciona os nomes na lista.
O método `exibir_veiculo` imprime todos os atributos.

```
class Veiculo(object):

    ex_proprietarios = []


    def __init__(self, placa, modelo):

        self.placa = placa
        self.modelo = modelo


    def add_ex_proprietarios(self, nome):

        self.ex_proprietarios.append(nome)


    def exibir_veiculo(self):

        print(self.placa)
        print(self.modelo)
        print(self.ex_proprietarios)


carro = Veiculo("X1Y2Z3", "Opala")

carro.add_ex_proprietarios("Pedro")
carro.add_ex_proprietarios("Paulo")
carro.add_ex_proprietarios("Lucas")

carro.exibir_veiculo()
```

Saída

```
X1Y2Z3
Opala
['Pedro', 'Paulo', 'Lucas']
```